# NPC's getting stuck in the ground?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I keep finding that many NPC's are getting stuck in the floor, this is particularly bothersome for assassination targets and guards, who start shooting me and I can't even touch them, any fixes?

Comment: I'm assuming you're playing the PC version? I doubt it would cause this issue, but it'll probably impact your options.